# React Native Accessibility Set Focus

Tags: react-native, accessibility, setfocus

I am adding accessibility to a React Native project and I can't seem to figure something out.
I am using javascript `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);` to change the focus to a desired component on the page. While using the accessibility inspectory in xCode, I notice that this doesn't seem to be working, but whenever I use a `<Modal />` component, it always pushes the focus to the first element found within that modal window.

I have been searching through all of the documentation I can find on React Native, Accessibility, and Focus and can't seem to see how the change in focus to the `<Modal />` component is being achieved.

Any ideas?

Comment: have the same issue here... Did you manage to solve this?